# arduino counter with push button

Tags: arduino

I need some help with code about button counter.
I want to make a counter in Arduino. if I do pressed on button, Arduino will add count value +1.
I want if I hold a button, counter just add 1 value on count value..
I do this program for it..
please help me fixed the program :(

```
    int pulse = 7;
    unsigned long t;
    unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
    int execussionTime = 1;
    long count = 0;

    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin (9600);


    }

    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
      t = millis();
      if (digitalRead(pulse) == HIGH){
        if(t - previousMillis < execussionTime) // 0 < 1 --> true and doing count + 1
        {
        count++;
        }
       }
       if(digitalRead(pulse) == LOW){
       previousMillis = t; 
       }
        Serial.println(count);
        Serial.println(t);
        Serial.print("PM = ");
        Serial.println(previousMillis);
    }
```

Comment: [StateChangeDetection.ino](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.2/build/shared/examples/02.Digital/StateChangeDetection/StateChangeDetection.ino)

Comment: wow thank for program, it's really help if I add pull-down resistor :D